# How to read data from xml attributes recurssively and store it in CSV in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, saxparser

I have the xml data as follows below,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" s="2012-04-23" v="FIX.5.0SP2">
    <Batch ID="RPTTA111PUBLI20170509">
        <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="14" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="CONF" MarketSegmentDesc="FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%" Sym="CH0002741988" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="CHF" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
            <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="5" MtchAlgo="PT" />
            <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT" />
            <FlexProdEligs FlexProdEligCmplx="5" FlexProdElig="Y" />
            <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
                <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.01" />
                <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="5" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.01" />
                <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0" />
                <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1" />
                <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="75" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.15" />
                <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="347" PxRngProdCmplx="5" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.12" />
            </BaseTrdgRules>
            <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.102" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.230" SvcLctnSubID2="59500" />
            <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.103" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.231" SvcLctnSubID2="59501" />
            <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="3" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.114.97" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.114.113" SvcLctnSubID2="59501" />
            <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="3" SvcLctnID1="224.0.114.96" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.114.112" SvcLctnSubID2="59500" />
            <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.89" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.217" SvcLctnSubID2="59500" />
        </MktDef>
        <SecDef PriSetPx="158.39">
            <Instrmt ID="408805" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMPSX" MatDt="2017-06-08" MMY="201706" Mult="1" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="P" SettlSubMeth="4" PxPrcsn="2" MinPxIncr="0.01" MinPxIncrAmt="10">
                <AID AltID="1048612" AltIDSrc="M" />
                <AID AltID="XF000001RQD8" AltIDSrc="4" />
                <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-08" />
            </Instrmt>
            <MktSegGrp MktSegID="14">
                <SecTrdgRules>
                    <BaseTrdgRules>
                        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="75" />
                    </BaseTrdgRules>
                </SecTrdgRules>
            </MktSegGrp>
        </SecDef>
    </Batch>
</FIXML>
```

I want to read the data from this XML and store it in CSV file as below.

Column names should be the RootElementName_ChildElementName(if we have)_AttributeName. This format I should follow,

Suppose RootElement is FIXML and we have attributes "s" and "v" so the column name should be as follows FIXML_s, FIXML_v.

And the Child Elements Batch and MktDef the column names should be 
FIXML_Batch_ID and FIXML_Batch_MktDef_MktID like that it follows.

```
1) FIXML_s       FIXML_v     FIXML_Batch_ID        FIXML_Batch_MktDef_MktID  . . . . .
  "2012-04-23"  "FIX.5.0SP2" RPTTA111PUBLI20170509  XEUR ....
.
.
.
```

We have data like that for thousands of lines and when it reaches to the `"</SecDef>"`  the data should print in 2nd line and 3rd line like that it continues.

Can someone guide me on this. I am very new to working on XML data.

Comment: So what determines which attributes form a single line in the result?

Comment: For SecDef we have PriSetPx and for MktDef we have MktSegID. Based on these 2 attributes we will decide the result of each iteration.

Comment: Consider to simplify your XML snippet but then show and explain the full corresponding CSV you want to create with XSLT, explaining which elements and their attributes map to a line in the CSV. What is supposed to happen with all those `MDFeedTyps` with the same attributes, do they all belong to the same line or do they belong to different lines?

Comment: It should come to different lines. If we find any tags with same name and same attributes should come to next line Martin.

Comment: should the second line repeat those fields in MKTDef element?

Comment: Yes, It should repeat. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can take this is as a sample 
where

you have to desgn your own
style.xsl

hear is mine

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
topic,title,url
<xsl:for-each select="//topic"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /><xsl:value-of select="concat(',' , title, ',' , url,' ')" /></xsl:for-each></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the converter

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XMLToCSV {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File stylesheet = new File("/home/1/style.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("/home/1/xml.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("/home/1/howto.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}
```

You can formatt the output as you want using this

This is how my xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<howto>
    <topic id="1">
        <title>Java</title>
        <url>http://www.google.com</url>
    </topic>
    <topic id="2">
        <title>XML</title>
        <url>http://www.ab</url>
    </topic>
    <topic id="3">
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <url>http://www.tt</url>
    </topic>
    <topic id="4">
        <title>VBScript</title>
        <url>http://www.wewe</url>
    </topic>
</howto>
```

Hope this helped ...

Comment: I have tried in XSLT as well, but the problem I faced is that I am unable to get all the data from MDFeedTyps  and PxRngRules ... so on like that. Can you please help me how to get that data as well.

Comment: Please show how your :exact output csv looks like correspoding to your data,this would help .[compleate xml data to csv]

Comment: If you are using Saxon, then constructing a DOM tree just so you can transform it is very bad practice: transforming a DOM takes 5-10 times longer than transforming a native Saxon TinyTree. You should supply the source as a StreamSource or SAXSource.

Comment: @ Michael Kay -Founder and Director at Saxonica Limited, it's an honor to get response from you. Thank you sir.  :)